# How to create a label or a text in gridview to overwrite certain cells for certain conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I’m working with asp.net and I have created a grid view as below. When Status text is set to a particular status I want to cover all of the cells, apart from the status text, in that row with a warning.

The data comes from an MQ string and is managed by a separate class. I’m thinking that a row databound event might be the way to go. I’m thinking something like the code below

Gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridDisc"  GridLines="none" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="2" HeaderStyle-backColor="#CCEEFF" OnRowDataBound="gridDisc_RowDataBound" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ep1" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusText" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPartDesc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UOI" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStockDetails" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDealerInv" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Listprice" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DiscCode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OptiInd" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Weight" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ExchangeSurcharge" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gridDisc_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            PartEnquiryLine line = (PartEnquiryLine)e.Row.DataItem;
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatusDetails");
             if (line.StatusText == Text["280"])
            {
                lbl.Text = Text["290"]
            }
```

But I haven’t been able to find any guidance on how to create a label that would cover specific cells in that row when triggered. I may be way off with this, but how would I do it?

Comment: Your question is certainly confusing please be a little less ambiguous thanks

Comment: Ah ok sorry. When the grid view is produced it consists of various cells which are databound, the first being status, when status is "invalid" (Text["280"]), I want that cell to display invalid (which it does) but the rest of the cells in that row to be covered over by some text, in this case the text is set as a literal (Text["290"]). I'm trying to figure out how to do that. Does that make sense?

Comment: In which column of your gridview you have `lblStatusDetails` control? I cannot see it in your posted markup.

Comment: @Suil Thanks for commenting, I haven't at that moment, that's what I'm struggling with, I need cells 0 and 1 to have their usual data in them and then the following cells to be covered by the label and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @AndyDouthwaite, Try the code that I have provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below. I am assuming you wanted to use `lblStockDetails` for showing the warning message since there is no `lblStatusDetails` column in your grid view.

Use the following code within the if part when you want a warning message to span multiple columns.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       PartEnquiryLine line = (PartEnquiryLine)e.Row.DataItem;
       Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStockDetails");
       if (line.StatusText == Text["280"])
       {
               lbl.Text = Text["290"]

                e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[4].ColumnSpan = 9;
                e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;;
                e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[9].Visible = false;;
                e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
     }
```

Comment: thanks, that's pointing me in the right direction, I need to put the label in the Colspan, is that possible?

Comment: No need to put any label as  this code should work with your existing code. I have set the colspan for lblStockDetails in above code and it should work with your existing markup.

Comment: Thanks,  this doesn't quite work for me, I get an error: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values." from e.row.Cells.RemoveAt(7). If I remove those lines, I can see that the ColumSpan (colspan won't work for some reason) is working, although not displaying the desired text.  I've tried a few things to resolve but now I'm going to try turning column 2 into a label and build it that way.

Comment: Try the updated code that I have just posted. Make sure that  your grid had 11 columns defined in markup.

Comment: that's has done the trick, thank you. My upvote doesn't register as I don't have the reputation but I'm very grateful.

Comment: @AndyDouthwaite, no problems and you're always welcome.